# express.static() cannot get favicon and files without index.html in build folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

express can't find static files in build folder. express can serve files in static folder now. but only problem that file path likes `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>` in `index.html` it reach `res.send('ERROR')`

however, when I change favicon and manifest path like `<link rel="icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico"/>`. it serve file I expected.

- add : I found that if url is `localhost//favicon.ico`, can access favicon.ico in build folder. (not in assets). only double slash can access build folder, single slash cannot access that. Is my express startpoint `localhost/` not `localhost`?

```
    server  
    |-server.js
    |-build  
      |-static  
        |-assets  
          |-favicon.ico
          |-manifest.json
        |-index.html  
        |-favicon.ico  
        |-manifest.json
```

```
    localhost => return index.html good  
    localhost/index.html, favicon.ico, else... => return ERROR  
    localhost/assets/favicon.ico, manifest.json => return files good
    localhost//index.html, favicon.ico. else... => return files good
```

```
    app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/static')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
    app.use('/*', (req, res) => res.send('ERROR');
```

Comment: Are those files (and the `assets` folder) in `static` or in `build`?

Comment: I edit tree clearly and update new founded issue. thx.